# Outlook VBA Stumbling Over "Undeliverable" Report

Tags: vba, outlook

I have VBA code that marks selected messages as read, assigns a category and moves them to a subfolder.

Mail Delivery System "Undeliverable" reports are not marked-as-read, categorized or moved.

I tried to duplicate the For Each loop to look for `olReportItem`. (I realize that it is inefficient to have two loops, but am just doing it this way for testing purposes so I can keep all the beta code in one section.)

```vb
Sub TestMoveToSubfolder()
'With selected emails: (1) mark as read, (2) assign category, (3) move to subfolder

On Error Resume Next

    Dim thisFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objStore As Store

    Set thisFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Set objStore = thisFolder.Store
    Set objFolder = thisFolder.Folders("REFERENCE_DESIRED_FOLDER")
        
    'Be sure target folder exists
    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "I can't find the designated subfolder.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "INVALID SUBFOLDER"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Confirm at least one message is selected
    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Loop through emails
    For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
            If objItem.Class = olMail Then
                objItem.UnRead = False
                objItem.Categories = "INSERT_DESIRED_CATEGORY"
                objItem.Move objFolder
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    'TEST SECTION to work with undeliverable reports
        Dim objItem2 As Outlook.ReportItem
        
        'Loop through nondelivery reports
        For Each objItem2 In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
            If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
                If objItem2.Class = olReportItem Then
                    objItem2.UnRead = False
                    objItem2.Categories = "INSERT_DESIRED_CATEGORY"
                    objItem2.Move objFolder
                End If
            End If
        Next
        
        Set objItem2 = Nothing
    
    Set thisFolder = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objStore = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is misused about 99.9999999% of the time so you are not alone. Remove it to see the error. Search the site for the solution.

Comment: `olReportItem` class does not exist, I'm afraid. Please, try `olReport` instead... And comment `On Error Resume Next`, as (correctly) has been stated in the above comment. `objItem` should be declared `As Variant` or `As Object`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to declaring the `objItem` in the following way:

```
Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
```

or

```
Dim objItem2 As Outlook.ReportItem
```

To be able to iterate over all items selected in Outlook you need to declare the `objItem` as `object` in the code.

Typically to find out the exact line of code causing the issue you need to remove the following line:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

There also no need to have two separate loops, you may combine two conditions into the single loop:

```
Dim objItem As Object

'Loop through emails
For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection      
  ' check for regular mail items
  If objItem.Class = olMail Then
     objItem.UnRead = False
     objItem.Categories = "INSERT_DESIRED_CATEGORY"
     objItem.Move objFolder
  End If
  ' check for report items
  If objItem.Class = olReportItem Then
     objItem.UnRead = False
     objItem.Categories = "INSERT_DESIRED_CATEGORY"
     objItem.Move objFolder
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, no `olReportItem` class exists. Declaring `objItem As Variant` (or `As Object`) will allow iteration between all selection clases (in a unique iteration. Something like that:

```
    Dim objItem 
    For Each objItem In appOutlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
            If objItem.Class = olMail Then
                objItem.UnRead = False
                objItem.Categories = "INSERT_DESIRED_CATEGORY"
                objItem.Move objFolder
            ElseIf objItem.Class = olReport Then
                Stop
                'do whatever you need here...
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the final working code is below.  I don't want to mark this as the answer since that seems like I am trying to take credit for the work of @niton, @FaneDuru and @Eugene Astafiev, but thanks to their input the question has been answered and the problem is solved.

```
Sub TestMoveToSubfolder()
'With selected emails: (1) mark as read, (2) assign category, (3) move to subfolder

Dim thisFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objItem As Object 'could also define as Variant
Dim objStore As Store 'used if you want to find subfolder of current mailbox

'set folder locations
    Set thisFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder 'alternative is Set thisFolder =  objItem.Parent
    Set objStore = thisFolder.Store 'alternative is to bypass thisFolder and use Set objStore = objItem.Parent.MAPIFolder.Store
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objFolder = thisFolder.Folders("REFERENCE_DESIRED_FOLDER")
    On Error GoTo 0

'Be sure target folder exists
    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "I can't find the designated subfolder.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "INVALID FOLDER"
        Exit Sub
    End If

'Require that this procedure be called only when a message is selected
    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

'Loop through selected items
    For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
            If objItem.Class = olMail Then
                objItem.UnRead = False
                objItem.Categories = "INSERT_DESIRED_CATEGORY"
                objItem.Save
                If thisFolder <> objFolder Then objItem.Move objFolder
            ElseIf objItem.Class = olReport Then
                objItem.UnRead = False
                objItem.Categories = "INSERT_DESIRED_CATEGORY"
                objItem.Save
                If thisFolder <> objFolder Then objItem.Move objFolder
            End If
        End If
    Next

'Clean up
    Set thisFolder = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objStore = Nothing

End Sub
```